# Why is this highscore glitching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

For some reason, the highscore on the game over page is not properly displayed. After a round of play, both the score and highscore are displayed on the game over menu. The score is displayed fine, but in the event that the user beats their highscore, it doesn't update, until the menu is reloaded.

If thats confusing:

Game 1: score = 30, previous highscore displayed = 10

Game 2: score = 40, previous highscore displayed = 30

Game 3: score = 10, highscore displayed = 30

**So essentially it doesn't display the new highscore when it is achieved, until the next time the game over menu is loaded.**

This is the code:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    score = _debris.count + _debris2.count;
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];

}
```

and in the `initWithSize` method:

```
highScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreSaved"];
if (score > highScoreNumber) {
    highScoreNumber = score;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScoreNumber forKey:@"highScoreSaved"];
```

That's the code in the game, and this is the code on the game over menu:

```
    SKLabelNode *highScore = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
    highScore.fontSize = 40;
    highScore.alpha = 0.7;
    highScore.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    highScore.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-15);

    highScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreSaved"];
    highScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEST: %d", highScoreNumber];
```

Based on this, is there any reason as to why the highscore isn't updating when there is a new highscore, but instead waiting until the gamoever screen is reloaded?

Comment: Are you calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` right after `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScoreNumber forKey:@"highScoreSaved"];`? That will ensure the data is saved immediately.

Comment: No but I tried it and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: Great :) should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes @MatíasR you should.

Comment: Yes @MatíasR I'll select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` right after `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScoreNumber forKey:@"highScoreSaved"];`? That will ensure the data is saved immediately.